# Why isn't the ‘P’ in psychology pronounced?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, orthography, silent-letters, consonants

Why is the initial letter of some of the words like *pneumonia*, and *psychology* not pronounced?

Answer (score 4):

It is an English phonetic adaptation of Greek words:

There are a number of Greek onset clusters imported into English:

'gn-' as in 'gnostic'

'pn-' as in 'pneumonia'

'pt-' as in 'pterodactyl'

'ps-' as in 'psychology'

> - The 'g' and 'p' are not silent in Greek. But /gn/, /pn/, /pt/, /ps/ are not legal onsets in English phonology. ***English speakers naturally dropped the first sound to make it more compatible with English.***

From [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-the-silent-P-in-psychic)