# Reason for silent letters before "n"

Tags: silent-letters

What is the reason, historical or otherwise, that many consonants are silent when they appear before "n". Examples:
Gnome
Pneumonia
Mnemonic
Knowledge

Comment: If I have time later, I'll add a real answer, but they used to be pronounced like consonant sequences, then English lost those sequences (or never had them and just spelled them that way) so now we just pronounce the "n."

Comment: Partial duplicate of [Why isn't the ‘P’ in psychology pronounced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/328003/191178)

Comment: Have you looked up the etymology of these words. Search for etymology online.

Answer (score -1):

In 793AD, 
The Vikings from Denmark and Norway with their Old Norse language invaded.
After fighting the Anglo-Saxons they settled down together and gave English
loads of words including the silent letter words: knife, knock, knee, know, gnat, gnaw, gnash, gnarl... The silent ‘k' and 'g' used to be pronounced, but we leave the letters in there to show the origin and history of the word.

The Anglo-Saxon and Viking languages became Old English.

Old English Letter Patterns: Many modern English letter patterns with silent letters in them come from Old
English: -igh, -gh, wh-, -lk, wr-.

Comment: Well, *whether* and *weather* aren't perfect homophones for some speakers even now.

Comment: "The silent ‘k' and 'g' used to be pronounced, but we leave the letters in there to show the origin and history of the word." This sentence is correct, but some of the other stuff in this answer isn't. The term "Old English" is only used to refer to Anglo-Saxon, not Viking. There are a number of words spelled with "kn-" that aren't from Viking (i.e. Norse, North Germanic) languages. As far as I can tell, "knife" is from North Germanic, but "know" isn't. "Knight" also doesn't seem to be from Norse.